# Mod ReWrite to remove component of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I must be an idiot because I just can't work this bit out.

I've got a URL:
www.site.com.au/products/product-name.html

I need to redirect these to:
www.site.com.au/product-name.html

All the links are dynamic, the folder doesn't exist. What ReWrite rule do I use to accomplish this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|test)\.site\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/products/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^.+\.html$ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Just need to add the bit to remote /products

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I really don't know enough about Apache Rewrite to figure out the exact formatting. But after much ado these are the results that worked:

```
# Lowercase all /products/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.site\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/.+\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]

# Lowercase all /products/ and strip products/ subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.site2\.com\.au
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/.+\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^products/(.+\.html)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,

Dom

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^products(/.*)$ http://www.site.com.au$1 [L, R=301]
```

This replaces everything you listed, except for the first RewriteCond (to match the domain, though if your VirtualHost only answers on those two domains, you can exclude that RewriteCond to simplify it).

RewriteRules are matched first before Apache looks at the RewriteConds, so if you can do the match in the RewriteRule itself it greatly simplifies things. Just for your future reference, if you did need to match in the RewriteCond, it would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.site.com.au%1 [L, R=301]
```

Note the `%1` for matching what's in the parentheses in the RewriteCond vs. the `$1` for matching what's in the RewriteRule.

EDIT: Per your comment, the following modification should force lowercase. I haven't had to do that myself, but per [this Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int) it's an internal function via RewriteMap. Based on your original code it looks like maybe you already have the RewriteMap definition elsewhere. If not, I've included it here.

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products(/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.site.com.au${lc:%1} [L, R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but is seems this doesn't include the lc component though - we need to lowercase the entire URL...

Comment: Not something I've done before, but I updated the answer with what I believe will force lowercase.